# is there a way to dump an entire mongodb collection into the oplog?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoid, mongodb-query

I am setting up a new ElasticSearch instance using the mongo-connector python tool. The tool is working, but only imported around ~100k entries from the mongodb oplog.

However, my collections contain millions of records... Is there a way to pass all the records from each collection through the oplog without modifying the records in any way?

Comment: You could manually inset straight to the oplog but a better option is instead to make a importer script which will actually import all your old records into ES

Comment: thats a good idea; would the import script you're envisioning more or less be a mongodump to json that is then imported to elasticsearch?

Comment: Pretty much, you would use the API http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html to just index them straight in your favourite language, i.e. PHP, should do it really quickly on only a couple of million

Comment: @Sammaye: FYI, you definitely should not attempt to manually insert or update entries in the MongoDB oplog. The format is internal to replication and messing with the oplog data will likely lead you to an unexpected outcome (i.e. broken replication and/or data loss).

Comment: I would recommend following the instructions to [Resync the Connector](https://github.com/10gen-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Resyncing%20the%20Connector) (which will dump & reindex all data and then start tailing the oplog). The ElasticSearch API is also an alternative, but may be extra work versus using the connector as intended.

Comment: @Stennie tbh I would say it is a bad idea to rely on the oplog for syncing to ES at all, in a proper environment I can think of at least 2 problems, but that aside it was a glancing mention of which I quickly turned to mentioning a different approach

Comment: @sammaye It's fine to use the oplog for keeping in sync with changes to a MongoDB deployment; this is the same mechanism used by replication. *Reading* the oplog via a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) is encouraged (although Mongo Connector or similar add a better API than reading the oplog directly); *writing* to the oplog is discouraged, as this crosses into dangerous territory of messing with replication internals.

Comment: @Stennie well replication has a certain amount of garauntee about it, a search instance does not, it relies upon the fact that it simply is able to index as fast as the window of the oplog. Only other option is to possibly over extend the oplog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the advice of Sammaye, I solved this problem by iterating over the collection, converting to json, and posting it to the index API via curl. Thanks for the suggestion!